# Como posso usar .getText mais de uma vez no java e como usar .getText com números

Tags: java

Eu estou tentando usar o .getText, mas ele retorna um erro "The method getText() is undefined for the type String" quando eu uso mais de uma vez, como posso resolver esse problema?

Com dupla asterisco(**) a parte que retorna erro

````
package ProjetoPessoas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class teste implements ActionListener{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JLabel label;
        JTextField nome;
        JTextField idade;
        JTextField funcao;
        JTextField sexo;
        JLabel passwordLabel;
        JPasswordField passwordText;
        JButton button;
        JLabel sucess;
        
        Aluno p1 = new Aluno();
        Professor p2 = new Professor();
        Funcionario p3 = new Funcionario();
           
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
            
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        label = new JLabel("Função"); 
        label.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(label);
            
        funcao = new JTextField(20); 
        funcao.setBounds(80,20,165,25);
        panel.add(funcao);
            
        label = new JLabel("Nome"); 
        label.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(label);
            
        nome = new JTextField(20); 
        nome.setBounds(80,50,165,25);
        panel.add(nome);
        
        label = new JLabel("Sexo"); 
        label.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(label);
        
        sexo = new JTextField(20); 
        sexo.setBounds(80,80,165,25);
        panel.add(sexo);
        
        label = new JLabel("Idade"); 
        label.setBounds(10, 110, 80, 25);
        panel.add(label);
        
        idade = new JTextField(20); 
        idade.setBounds(80,110,165,25);
        panel.add(idade);
            
            
        button = new JButton("Entrar"); 
        button.setBounds(10, 200, 80, 25);
        button.addActionListener(new teste() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
                String user = nome.getText();
                p1.setNome(user);   

                **String sexo = sexo.getText();**
                p1.setNome(sexo);
                
                **String funcao = funcao.getText();**
                p1.setFuncao(funcao);
                
                **String idade = idade.getText();**
                p1.setIdade(idade);
                
                System.out.println("Nome: "+p1.toString());
            }
        }); 
        panel.add(button);
        
          
            
        sucess = new JLabel(""); 
        sucess.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25); 
        panel.add(sucess);
            
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}```
````

Comment: A mensagem de erro diz que o tipo `string` não possui um método `getText`. Acho que tu podes usar direto a variável em vez de chamar `getText`...

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro foi declarar variáveis string com o mesmo nome de campos da sua tela, por isso gera esta mensagem, pois o java entende que você está tentando acessar o método das variáveis string recém criadas.

Variáveis nunca devem ter o mesmo nome de outras, muito menos quando fazem parte do mesmo escopo, como é o caso dos campos de texto `nome`, `sexo`, `funcao` e `idade` do seu código e das variáveis strings homônimas.

```
            String strSexo = sexo.getText();
            p1.setNome(sexo);
            
            String strFuncao = funcao.getText();
            p1.setFuncao(funcao);
            
            String strIdade = idade.getText();
            p1.setIdade(idade);
```

Esta seria uma das formas de contornar esse problema.